# Ruby - CSV Import split data into different tables

Tags: ruby, csv, import, rake

I'm trying to import a csv file with a rake task. The csv looks like this

```
model,brand,type,engine,price,doors
Corsa,Opel,cupe,1100,14500,2
Corsa,Opel,cupe,1100,1450,2
Impreza,Subaru,sedan,1200,25000,4
```

My table structure looks like this though

```
# Tables
Brands: id, brand_name
Models: id, brand_id, model_name, type_id, engine, price, doors
Types: id, car_type (cupe, sedan etc)
```

This is my rake task

```
require "csv"

namespace :import do
  desc "Import cars from CSV"
  task cars: :environment do
    file = File.join(Rails.root, "cars.csv")
    CSV.foreach(file, headers: true) do |row|
      p row
    end
  end
end
```

How can I import the data and split them into the different tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `#each` create each `ActiveRecord` instance like this:

```
brand = Brand.find_or_create_by(brand_name: row['brand'])
type = Type.find_or_create_by(car_type: row['car_type'])
Model.create(
  brand: brand,
  type: type,
  model_name: row['model_name'],
  engine: row['engine'],
  price: row['price'],
  doors: row['doors'])
```

Comment: Just to confirm, the `create` (without the `!`) will create the records only if they are no duplicates, right? what I mean is if a row on the csv appears more than once it shouldn't re-created as a record on the db

Comment: No. In that case, you should use `find_or_create_by` for `Model` as well. Another option is to create validations in the model.

Comment: This works fine when you have one-to-many relationships., but what about many-to-many where you use pivot tables? If lets say I have a `brands_models` table how do I insert the the rows for brandID and modelID in this case?

Comment: You will have to create the `Model` separately. First do `model = Model.find_or_create_by(...) ` and then create the relation if not already exists `BrandModel.find_or_create_by(model: model, brand: brand)`

Comment: Sorry I come back again on this, but I'm just curious, is there a better or more clever way of importing the data from CSV? Because right now, although your solution works fine, I query the database on every iteration to check if records already exists when using `find_or_create`

Comment: Well, I'll not get deep into details, but one idea is to cache your instances in a `Hash` (or an ordered `Array`) and search for them before making another query for the same record. Got it? Another idea for performance improvements is to run the whole interaction in a database transaction -- avoiding multiple commits will make it way faster.